# backup tidy up script

Tags: windows, command

I've looked around here for an answer to my question but it doens't look like anyone has so far got there.

I'm looking for a way to selectively DELETE files from a directory, so I have; 
Every file in the last 7 days
one file for every 30 days.

So in effect I've got last week and then a file for each month. I'd like to use a batch script to do the delete or a GUI, I don't mind, but it needs to be something I can schedule. At the moment I'm hand tweening out the files...

Most of the answers are for linux; 
[daily, weekly, yearly backup script](https://serverfault.com/questions/169727/daily-weekly-yearly-backup-script)
this one seems close.

Would appreciate any help as it'll shave valuable minutes of my day and free up some storage.

Comment: No worries, I'm sure everyone here will be only too happy to waste their time if it will save a few minutes of yours.

Comment: Hi John - I was being facetious, obviously lost on you.

Answer (score 4):

The forfiles command can select files based on their ages, so something like this could be used to delete log files 7 or more days old:

forfiles /d -7 /c "cmd /c echo @file"

To save a monthly copy, use the task scheduler to copy that file to an archive folder once a month.

Comment: Thanks Ramruma, I've been thinking about this and I think it might be a good idea to write a little app to do it. If I do I'll post on here so people with the same problem can use it.