# Simple bash backup solution

Tags: bash

I have a **very** limited experience with shell scripting and would like to put in place some sort of script that backs up my blog (Wordpress) on a weekly basis.

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

# Determine current date
setenv CURDATE date +%Y%m%d

# Backup DB & email it to me
mysqldump dbname -u user -ppassword | gzip | uuencode ${CURDATE}dbname.sql.gz | mail -s "backup for dbname ${CURDATE}" my@email.com

cd /home/myhome

# Zip blog
tar cf - blog.mysite.me | gzip - > ~/backups/${CURDATE}blog.mysite.me.tar.gz
```

And this is where I am a bit stuck... I was thinking about emailing myself the blog directory but what happens when this becomes bigger then 10MB or so? how would I script this to split this and email me the chunks?

Another suggestion I have which I feel is better is to FTP the backups to another VPS that I own. But for the sake of space I would like to only keep the last 10 backups. How would I implement the part of the script script that:

1. Upload backup
2. Get list of files
3. Gets count of files in the current dir (e.g. /home/myhome/backups/blog )
4. If count > 10 delete oldest

Any help/advice or pointers with solving this problem would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather then zipping it and ftping, use rsync over the network.  If you make a new directory for each date, and  use the --link-dest option to link it back to the previous directory, it will only store the changed files, and files that don't change will be a hard link to the previous one.

I posted some code at [What backup solution you use for linux servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/3218/what-backup-solution-you-use-for-linux-servers/3249#3249)

Comment: This is what I'm using for backups. It's really nice, because I have over 330GB of data backed up with a week's worth of daily snapshots (i.e. full, not incremental, backups), and yet the filesystem hosting those 7 days of backups uses the same amount of space! Expanding it to more days, or by adding weekly and monthly snapshots, would be the same story.

Answer (score 4):

First, to set a variable from a command use

```
CURDATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

instead of

```
setenv CURDATE date +%Y%m%d
```

If you want to leave only 10 days of backup, you can do that deleting the backup that was made 10 days ago. Use `date` relative commands to find it and save to another variable:

```
PAST_DATE=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y" --date="10 days ago")
```

Second, you can use `lftp` to execute ftp commands on a single line, like this:

```
lftp -u user,pass server -e "mrm *${PAST_DATE}.sql.gz; exit;
```

If you use the date on the file names, and each day remove the files that are 10 day old, you can do exactly what you are thinking. You can use `lftp` to put the files too, it works like a regular client, just that it works on a single line.

Comment: If you have shell access of some kind to the remote host (likely?) you can also use find to delete files older than 10 days: `find /backup/dir -type f -mtime -10 -exec rm -f '{}' \;`. This is probably simpler and more robust than figuring out the filename of the right file to delete.